# watchOS application is not opening in background after scheduling

Tags: watch

Apple Watch Series 3 watchOS 4.x.x, iPhone 6 iOS 11.x.x, Xcode 9.2

I downloaded the code from the following link:

[SOURCE CODE](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/WatchBackgroundRefresh/Listings/WatchBackgroundRefresh_WatchKit_Extension_MainInterfaceController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017295-WatchBackgroundRefresh_WatchKit_Extension_MainInterfaceController_swift-DontLinkElementID_8)

Then able to install and run this swift application on my apple watch.

As per code, I tapped "Schedule Refresh" button and put my app in background by pressing crown button. Then app was not opening in background for making server call.

I was expecting, following function will be called, but not
`func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) { }`

So, please let me know if anyone tried this sample app to run watch application in background.

Comment: You don't mention your project settings.  Have you looked at the app entitlements?  Background processing is only allowed when the appropriate app entitlement is enabled.

Comment: I enabled Background Mode. There are two entries Lacation and Workout. I checked both. Any other thing I am missing?

Comment: Anything I need to add in provisioning file?